# Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps Api on ReactJS with the least npm modules possible. So I'm adding the script to the window object myself. But Typescript jumps after a saying: "Property 'google' does not exist on type 'Window'".

I tried adding a property google: any to the Window interface but it doesn't work, and I can't find the proper interface inside the google types.

This is my code:

```
private initMap = () => {
this.setState({
  map: new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: this.state.userPosition.lat,
      lng: this.state.userPosition.lng
    },
    zoom: this.state.zoom,
    mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  })
});

this.setState({
  rangeCircle: new window.google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#007AFF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#007AFF",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: this.state.map,
    center: {
      lat: this.state.userPosition.lat,
      lng: this.state.userPosition.lng
    },
    radius: this.state.radius * 1000
  })
});

this.setState({
  centerMarker: new window.google.maps.Marker({
    icon: { locationIcon },
    map: this.state.map,
    position: this.state.userPosition
  })
});
```

};

```
private renderMap = () => {
    loadScript(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*********&callback=initMap"
    );
    window.initMap = this.initMap;
  };
}

function loadScript(url: string) {
  const index = window.document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  const script = window.document.createElement("script");

  script.src = url;
  script.async = true;
  script.defer = true;

  if (index.parentNode) {
    index.parentNode.insertBefore(script, index);
  }

}
```

--------------UPDATE------------------

I created this interface:

```
interface IGoogle {
    maps: {
        Circle: google.maps.Circle;
        Map: google.maps.Map;
        Marker: google.maps.Marker;
    }
}
```

And added a google property inside Window:

```
interface Window extends EventTarget, WindowTimers, WindowSessionStorage, WindowLocalStorage, WindowConsole, GlobalEventHandlers, IDBEnvironment, WindowBase64, GlobalFetch, WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope, WindowEventHandlers {
    google: IGoogle;
    initMap: () => void;
```

**And it still returns the same error.**

Answer (score 39):

You need Google Map's TypeScript definition, this can be achieved with the command `npm i @types/google.maps --save-dev`

Revision: per [@timarcosdias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338054/timarcosdias), the package is updated to `@types/google.maps`

Comment: I already added that, I'm using it for defining the circle and markers, but there is no type for the whole thing, just for the different classes like Map and Circle, it's all wrapped in a namespace.

Comment: Post your tsconfig.json if you still experience the problem

Comment: This package has moved to `@types/google.maps`.

Comment: I can't install that package because it doesn't work with TS 5.x apparently

Answer (score 5):

this may help if you want to access google maps property from window if its already loaded.

```
const { maps } = (window as any).google;
```

Answer (score 2):

why you are using the `window.google` and not like this

just add this on top of your class outside

```
declare const google: any;
```

and then used like this.

```
map: new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
```

or install the typings.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the fix that worked for me was to add it as a `<script>` tag to the `index.html`.

The benefit is that now you don't need to use `withScriptjs` and have a `mapURL` on each component.

Answer (score -4):

Adding

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY"></script>
```

To the `index.html` file worked for me.